# How to do Basic Oracle Sql Commands task Using HR Data Model

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

Link To Data Model That I need to use for this question. Check my sql code.

[image: data model]
<sub>(source: [databasejournal.com](http://www.databasejournal.com/img/sc_CASETools2_image004.jpg))</sub>

My Task for my self is to find The total number of employees of each job type in a particular location (i.e. the location ID or city should be input by the user).

The job title, city location and country name should also be included.

My Code That I am trying to work on. It's not working though I try many things but showing different errors such as Column ambiguously defined, no group by allowed here, not a valid identifier. I am using oracle apex to do everything.

```
SELECT job_title, city,country_name,location_id, count(j.job_id) "number of employees"
FROM hr.employees, hr.jobs, hr.locations, hr.countries, hr.departments
WHERE employees.job_id = jobs.job_id
AND Countries.country_id = Locations.country_id
AND Locations.location_id = departments.location_id
GROUP BY job_title, city, country_name, location_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using the 21st-century version 
of the `JOIN` command, because it's far
easier to use and troubleshoot.

You should also consider qualifying all your
column names by table to disambiguate them.

Try this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.employee_id) "number of employees",
        j.job_title,
        l.city,
        c.country_name,
        l.location_id
   FROM hr.employees e
   JOIN hr.departments d  ON e.department_id = d.department_id
   JOIN hr.locations l    ON d.location_id = l.location_id
   JOIN hr.countries c    ON l.country_id = c.country_id
   JOIN hr.jobs j         ON e.job_id = j.job_id
  GROUP BY j.job_title, l.city, c.country_name, l.location_id
```

Notice the `COUNT(DISTINCT e.employee_id)` item in the `SELECT` clause. This makes it
clear to another programmer that you're counting employees in your aggregate query. You
can replace that with `COUNT(*)` and get the same exact results.

If you wish to report on a subset of your employees, you can insert a `WHERE` clause immediately before the `GROUP BY` clause.  For example, you could do this:

```
WHERE l.city = 'New York' AND c.country_name = 'US'
```

But of course you need to know the city names and country names actually appearing in your data to get this right.

You could also append `WITH ROLLUP` to the end of your `GROUP BY` clause. If you do that, change the order of your fields, using this version of `GROUP BY`.

```
  GROUP BY ROLLUP(c.country_name, l.city, l.location_id, j.job_title)
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I should have put  `ON l.country_id = c.country_id`. I edited my answer.

Comment: You Are A legend Sir. Heads off to you. It worked Amazingly. I Wish there would have something bigger than thankyou So I could have said that to you. Anyway Please Do keep eye on my profile as I will post more SQL Questions And I will really Appreciate If you will Answer Them. Once Again Thankyou So Much